# Agregar a una contraseña MD5 o SHA1

Tags: mysql, login, seguridad, md5, sha1

necesito un poco de ayuda.

Verán tengo un sistema de inicio de sesión bastante sencillo, sin embargo la contraseña se almacena y se "compara" al logueo en texto plano.

Deseo saber si me pueden ayudar a saber que puedo hacer para agregarle a la contraseña algo de seguridad.

El código que controla mi inicio de sesión es el siguiente:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION["session_username"])){
// echo "Session is set"; // for testing purposes
header("Location: intropage.php");
}

if(isset($_POST["login"])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $query =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");

    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)

    {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['username'];
    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
    }

    if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)

    {


    $_SESSION['session_username']=$username;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: intropage.php");
    }
    } else {

 $message =  "Nombre de usuario ó contraseña invalida!";
    }

} else {
    $message = "Todos los campos son requeridos!";
}
}
?>
```

El formulario HTML es el siguiente:

```
 <div class="container mlogin">
            <div id="login">
    <center><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imageen/2021/05/27/ccd9783d5c8bb97d43b3d2052fbab0b2.png"></center>
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="" method="POST">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">Nombre De Usuario<br />
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Contraseña<br />
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
        <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="login" class="button" value="Entrar" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Como detalle adicional en la base de datos el campo "password" es del tipo VARCHAR(32).

De antemano les agradezco a todo al que pueda su ayuda.

Actualización

Ya he conseguido que se guarde el hash en la base de datos, el codigo final es:

```
$password_hash=password_hash("$password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows==0)
    {
    $sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
            (full_name, email, username,password)
            VALUES('$full_name','$email', '$username', '$password_hash')";

    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Sin embargo no consigo adaptar el password_verify() a el login que es el código que muestro al inicio de esta pregunta. No se ni por donde empezar.

Notas adicionales

Logré hacer que funcionara, ya verifica la contraseña con password_verify()

El código completo es el siguiente

```
if(isset($_POST["login"])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    // Reseteamos
    $dbusername = $dbpassword = $password = NULL;

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");

    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows!=0) {
     if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
         $dbusername=$row['username'];
         $dbpassword=$row['password'];
  }
}

// Contraseña obtenido desde login (no hay que encriptarla, tiene que ser origianl)
$password = $_POST['password']; // Contraseña obtenido desde formulario

// Verificar contraseña
if (password_verify($password, $dbpassword)) {


    $_SESSION['session_username']=$username;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: intropage.php");
    }
     else {

 $message =  "Nombre de usuario ó contraseña invalida!";
    }

} else {
    $message = "Todos los campos son requeridos!";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personalmente no aplicaría un **MD5** o **SHA1** solo, ya que son más vulnerables, piensa que existen páginas donde podemos descifrar fácilmente dichas contraseñas.

Si usamos `password_hash()`, hay que tener en cuenta una cosa muy importante para que luego lo puedas verificar correctamente, depende del algoritmo que usas hay que tener en cuenta la longitud de caracteres que se pueden guardar en tu Base de datos para la columna que va guardar la contraseña, veamos las diferencias:

> **PASSWORD_DEFAULT** - Usar el algoritmo bcrypt (predeterminado a partir de PHP 5.5.0). Observe que esta constante está diseñada para cambiar siempre que se añada un algoritmo nuevo y más fuerte a PHP. Por esta razón, la longitud del resultado de usar este identificador puede cambiar con el tiempo. Por lo tanto, se recomienda almacenar el resultado en una columna de una base de datos que pueda ampliarse a más de 60 caracteres (255 caracteres sería una buena elección).

> **PASSWORD_BCRYPT** - Usar el algoritmo CRYPT_BLOWFISH para crear el hash. Producirá un hash estándar compatible con crypt() utilizando el identificador "$2y$". El resultado siempre será un string de 60 caracteres, o false en caso de error.

En tu caso al usar *PASSWORD_DEFAULT* necesitas que tu columna donde se va guardar la contraseña tenga **255** caracteres permitidos, para así guardar correctamente la contraseña encriptada.

### **Un posible ejemplo:**

**Password_hash** — Crea un hash de contraseña.

Veamos como encriptar la contraseña obtenida por `POST` para guardar posteriormente en la Base de datos. Supongamos que la contraseña es: **rasmuslerdorf**

```
$contrasena_guardar_BD = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Crea algo como esto: $2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a

// Sigues con tu codigo.
// Guardar datos en la Base de datos
```

**Password_verify** — Comprueba que la contraseña coincida con un hash.

Respecto a tu duda, para verificar la contraseña hacemos lo siguiente:

En primre lugar, para obtener los datos del usuario solo usaremos `WHERE username=?`, es decir, eliminamos `AND password`, algo como:

```
// Reseteamos
$dbusername = $dbpassword = $password = NULL;

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows!=0) {
  if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     $dbusername=$row['username'];
     $dbpassword=$row['password'];
  }
}
 
// Contraseña obtenido desde login (no hay que encriptarla, tiene que ser origianl)
$password = $_POST['password']; // Contraseña obtenido desde formulario

// Verificar contraseña
if (password_verify($password, $dbpassword)) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}
```

Manual:
[password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)
[password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo usar una librería en javascript, porque de cualquier modo tendrás que enviar la password desde el cliente al servidor y lo mejor es enviarlas encriptadas.

[Librerias javascript md5,Sha-1](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/index.html)

Solo deberas cargar las librerias en el encabezado de tu página

```
<script src="js/md5-min.js" ></script>
<script src="js/sha1-min.js" ></script>
```

Luego a travez de javascript debes leer la variable del POST y hashearla con

```
password = hex_sha1(hex_md5(document.getElementById('pass').value));
```

Tomado como ejemplo 123456 te queda la siguiente cadena.
10470c3b4b1fed12c3baac014be15fac67c6e815

y así la almacenas en tu base y de igual manera la comparas cuando se haga el login.